# Installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on Lenovo Flex 5G ARM64 based laptop?

Tags: system-installation, usb, arm, 22.04, arm64

Good Evening:

I am running a Lenovo Flex 5G ARM64 based laptop.  It is currently running Windows 11.

I have used Ubuntu in the past and have enjoyed it very much, now that my needs and use have changed, I no longer want to be a part of the Microsoft / Windows ecosystem.

Here is what I have tried:

1. I have tried using the daily desktop build of 22.04 LTS for ARM64, and the server install for 22.04 LTS for ARM64.
2. I have tried creating the bootable USB pen using Rufus (both MBR and GPT), as well as Balena Etcher.
3. I also changed out USB drives to be sure that no equipment was defective.
4. I have tried combinations of Secure Boot ON, Fast Boot ON, OFF ON, OFF OFF, and ON OFF respectively.

I simply am unable to get this software to boot into the menu to choose Live or Install.

Reddit forums have not been helpful.  Someone has to have run into this - I can't be the only one trying to run Ubuntu on ARM64.

Can anyone provide some insight into this issue?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: You mention *dailies* where Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is now a released product, so why are you using *daily* ISOs?   You also weren't specific as to what *daily* you were using, detail needed so we can explore issues for that ISO as each differs to the prior one - why they're dated!

Comment: The only two possible downloads are: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ and the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ARM64 Server image.  I do not want to run the server edition as I am looking for a desktop replacement - but if I have to run Server to get this moving, I will have to...

Comment: For my Raspberry Pi I used: https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/release/ubuntu-22.04-preinstalled-desktop-arm64+raspi.img.xz

Comment: **CAUTION**, the link I posted above will download the image file. You can install it using Rufus, Etcher, Win32DiskImager, Gnome Disks or mkusb.